# What is the best way to update ListView?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, tabs

Good day,

I make my test application in Android and find some difficult moments to do by myself.

I have two Tab Fragments and Host Activity (that creates two tab fragments) with Action Bar (actionbarsherlock). One Fragment allows to add some information about product and persist it into SQLite. Other Fragment has a listview that displays all the products from database.

The problem is that in the first tab I persist data in different thread with 5 second delay, so you click "Add Product to Database" button and after 5 seconds it will be added. But right after clicking I can switch  to another tab with listview and the situation is as follows:  data from the first fragment is not persisted yet because of delay, but after it is persisted, nothing changes in listview - the listview doesn't know about changes.  I need listview updated authomatically when it notices there are changes in database. How can I do this? I use ArrayAdapter to populate data into listview.

Comment: so write `ContentProvider` and instead of `ArrayAdapter` use `CursorAdapter` ... to get fill `CursorProvider` use `CursorLoader` if you build proper `ContentProvider` refreshing `ListView` is implemented in `CursorAdapter` already ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need necessary use broadcast receiver, and in it call method refreshDrawableState() for you list. Respectively receiver is your activity.